# How do I use multi touch in a Python paint program?

Tags: python

I'm building a simple paint program in Python as a project, using Pygame it works by basically drawing a stream of circles when the mouse gets pressed and you drag it around the surface, it's got a couple other little things going on but the thing I want to ask is, is there a way to change the singular mouse input you know mouse.get_pressed to either multiple mouse inputs at one time or a multi-touch input into the point list that's streaming the circles.

running= True

while running:

```
if buttons[0] == True:
    x,y = pygame.mouse.get_pos()

    if x> PA+AS:
        xShift = x - PA - AS
        pygame.draw.circle(pArea,DRAW_CLR,(xShift,y),BRUSHSIZE)
        pygame.display.flip()
```

so this is the part of the code I really want to change more or less. Just so that instead of just one mouse, I could use my touchscreen to draw with maybe two finger.

Comment: Can you be more specific

Comment: I can try i guess so
running= True
while running:

    if buttons[0] == True:
        x,y = pygame.mouse.get_pos()

        if x> PA+AS:
            xShift = x - PA - AS
            pygame.draw.circle(pArea,DRAW_CLR,(xShift,y),BRUSHSIZE)
            pygame.display.flip()
pArea being the subsurface i'm drawing on and PA and AS being ints relative to the size of the surface. basically instead of just drawing with one input (the mouse) i wondered if there was a way to utilize my computers touchscreen, and draw with more then one finger at a time and how to do that.

Comment: You can update your question with your code. Avoid to add it in comments.

Answer (score 2):

Latest versions of pygame support multitouch input (and I believe also gestures).

The events which control it are `pygame.FINGERDOWN`, `.FINGERUP` and `.FINGERMOTION`. My understanding is that they work like mouse inputs, but can be multiple and can be distinguished by means of an `event.finger_id` property.

An example can be found here:
https://www.patreon.com/posts/finger-painting-43786073?l=fr

Answer (score 0):

You're going to have a difficult time if you insist on doing this in PyGame. Your best bet for multitouch in Python is [Kivy](http://kivy.org/#home), which was a very solid framework a few years ago when I used it and appears to have only gotten better since.

The disadvantage of switching to Kivy is a more complicated API, but [this tutorial](http://kivy.org/docs/guide/firstwidget.html) seems spot-on for what you're trying to do.

Comment: the advice is appreciated thank you. but for the purpose of this program it would be best if i dound some way to do it in PyGame. I'll try kivy if i run out of options

Comment: last version of pygame (I think it's version 2), supports multitouch. An example can be found here https://www.patreon.com/posts/finger-painting-43786073?l=fr